# How to use getApplicationContext() in uiautomator?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-context, android-uiautomator

i want to execute below code from uiAutomator Script,

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

To access `getSystemService(...)`    i need below functions

```
Context mContext = getInstrumentation().getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

So how to get it `(getApplicationContext)` working from `uiAutomator` Script Code ?

Answer (score 2):

You would not be able to get the Application context as `UIAutomator` is not a standalone android application

`UIAutomator` is a different framework altogether which runs similar to a script in shell and basically generates series of action events which usually application user might probably perform